# How to force SciTE to reload a file automatically?

Tags: editor, settings, scite

I think that SciTE can do it but it doesn't work for me. Is there any option to setup?

Comment: You may want to add the tags for the language/technogy SCiTe is implemented in / a part of. Otherwise, it won't show up on many people's "favourite" lists who might be competent to answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have set `load.on.activate=1` in my SciTEUser.properties which works like a charm.

EDIT:

Use it in combination with `save.on.deactivate=1` and `reload.preserves.undo=1`. The [SciTEDocs](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html) will tell you more.

Answer (score -2):

Add this line on the `SciTEUser.properties` file:

```
save.session=1
```